# Buildroot: How to make rootfs.ext2 not read-only

Tags: linux, buildroot, parsec

Hi I am working on building a disk image which can run PARSEC benchmarks on QEMU, I got everything working, but when I run a benchmark I get it tells me that it can't generate files because it is a read-only file system. Is there an option to disable this in Buildroot menuconfig?

Thanks all !

Answer (score 0):

There is an option `remount root filesystem read-write during boot` in the `System configuration` menu in `make menuconfig`. It defaults to on. If you disable it, the root filesystem will be readonly.

Comment: I marked this option but still filesystems are read only.

Comment: In that case, something else is amiss. Need more info. Also, it's basically asking for debugging an issue, which is not really appropriate for StackOverflow. Go to the Buildroot IRC channel or mailing list instead.